# Colour specific to factor on a facet-wrap GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

[column plot that I would like to colour according to season](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bj9z.jpg)I would like to Specify colour for Season (Spring/Autumn) in a multi facet plot of count and date.
I have data in this format:

```
Date = c("06/13/2011", "10/26/2011", "05/28/2012", "11/11/2012", "05/25/2013", "10/31/2013", "06/09/2014", "11/03/2014", "05/14/2015", "10/24/2015", "05/03/2016", "10/13/2016", "05/24/2017", "10/16/2017", "06/09/2018", "10/05/2018")
Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
y0_c = c(159375000, 29403750000, 0, 3665625000, 0, 25790000000, 0, 18636250000, 0, 13421875000, 0, 26098125000, 0, 1440625000, 82500000, 23101250000)
y1_c = c(1794375000, 313125000, 12065625000, 3148125000, 2883750000, 372500000, 2872500000, 790000000, 7604375000, 3496875000, 4042500000, 830000000, 20070000000, 10648750000, 771250000, 328750000)
y2_c = c(317500000, 42500000, 33750000, 62500000, 176875000, 331875000, 166250000, 54375000, 260000000, 116250000, 1068125000, 290000000, 438125000, 160000000, 2686250000, 1072500000)
y3_c = c(5625000, 5000000, 5625000, 1875000, 2500000, 4375000, 18125000, 7500000, 11875000, 22500000, 51250000, 37500000, 16250000, 31250000, 60000000, 38125000)

df = data.frame(Date, y0_c, y1_c, y2_c, y3_c)
df_melt = melt(df, id.vars = 'Date')

ggplot(dfc_melt, aes(x = Date, y = value)) + geom_col() + facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = 'free_y', ncol = 1)
```

This gives me a plot as in the image below.

[image]

I would like to colour the bars according to the season and attempted this using:
`Season = c("spring", "Summer", "Spring"......)` but this resulted in a Warning message:

> attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be
>   dropped

...I am a bit lost!

Thanks in advance if you're able to help

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Somehow managed to delete it!

Comment: click the edit button and write it down again

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea what you mean and where your problem is. To me it seems you are struggling with making a new **season** column. Even if I am wrong it was fun to exercise a bit.

To me making a function to check, in what season the Date in your data frame is, is the key. After loading the two necessary packages **tidyverse** and **reshape2**, the starting date for spring, summer, autumn and winter are defined, followed by a function which makes the above mentioned check. This function is then used to create a new column **season**.

This function takes advantage of the package **lubridate** which is included in **tidyverse**.

With melt this data frame is then transferred with the id.vars of *Date* and *season*.
ggplot makes then a bar chart with *geom_col* as I believe is about what you are looking for. The new data frame should give you a good platform to create other versions of a plot.

**As your original data only contained dates in spring or autumn, I changed one date to a summer date for checking**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

Date = c("06/13/2011", "10/26/2011", "07/28/2012", "11/11/2012", "05/25/2013", 
   "10/31/2013", "06/09/2014", "11/03/2014", "05/14/2015", "10/24/2015", "05/03/2016", 
    "10/13/2016", "05/24/2017", "10/16/2017", "06/09/2018", "10/05/2018")
Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
y0_c = c(159375000, 29403750000, 0, 3665625000, 0, 25790000000, 0, 18636250000, 0, 
   13421875000, 0, 26098125000, 0, 1440625000, 82500000, 23101250000)
y1_c = c(1794375000, 313125000, 12065625000, 3148125000, 2883750000, 372500000, 
   2872500000, 790000000, 7604375000, 3496875000, 4042500000, 830000000, 20070000000, 
   10648750000, 771250000, 328750000)
y2_c = c(317500000, 42500000, 33750000, 62500000, 176875000, 331875000, 166250000, 
   54375000, 260000000, 116250000, 1068125000, 290000000, 438125000, 160000000, 
   2686250000, 1072500000)
y3_c = c(5625000, 5000000, 5625000, 1875000, 2500000, 4375000, 18125000, 7500000, 
   11875000, 22500000, 51250000, 37500000, 16250000, 31250000, 60000000, 38125000)

winterStart <- "12-21"
springStart <- "03-23"
summerStart <- "06-21"
autumnStart <- "09-21"

season <- function(d) ifelse(d > ymd(paste(year(d), springStart, sep='-' )) &
                             d < ymd(paste(year(d),summerStart, sep='-')), 'spring',
                         ifelse(d > ymd(paste(year(d), summerStart, sep='-' )) &
                                    d < ymd(paste(year(d),autumnStart, sep='-')), 'summer',
                                ifelse(d > ymd(paste(year(d), autumnStart, sep='-' )) &
                                           d < ymd(paste(year(d),winterStart, sep='-')), 'autumn','winter')))

df = data.frame(Date, y0_c, y1_c, y2_c, y3_c)
df$season <- season(df[,1])
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars = c("Date", 'season'))
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars = c("Date", 'season'))

ggplot(df.melt, aes(Date, value, fill=season))+geom_col()
```

And here is my output
[image]

Hopefully this is about what you are looking for.